# Firebase: How to handle invalid firebaseConfig passed to firebase.initializeApp()

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am having an angular app which connects to 2 firebase projects:

1. The default project is connected on app load via `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)` (AngularFire2)
2. The secondary project is connected at run time via `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'pr1');` (Firebase JS SDK)

Now the firebase config of the 2nd project is received from user through UI. So I need to validate if the firebase project exists with given credentials, before I could do any operation.

Calling `res = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'pr1');` with invalid apiKey, authDomain, projectId, storageBucket, etc., is not throwing any error, but successfully returning a `FirebaseAppImpl` object.

After initialization, calling

- res.auth()
- res.storage()

also doesnt throw any errors but returning me proper objects.

Only for `res.database()`, I am getting a console warning as follows:

`@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (https://[invalid-url].firebaseio.com)`

But its not throwing any errors, that I could act on.

I need to validate the given keys, and alert the user that 1 or more key is wrong. Any suggestions on how to do this?

**Update 1**:
Had a look at Firebase Management API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest

- It has many functions like creating, retrieving projects.
- But I am not sure, how to make use of any of these APIs to my requirement.